# javascript output date in correct format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am wanting to output the Date with javascript in a specific format I am wanting to output in

> 2013-7-31 15:17:56

How would I go about doing this, I have googled around, and found functions like,

`getYear()` & `getMonth()` & `getDay()`

But I seem to get this output with those functions

> 2013-6-3

Comment: Have you tried moment.js? It is a small library for managing dates in javascript.  Really easy to implement in that.  http://momentjs.com/

Comment: If you're able to use libraries I would check out http://momentjs.com/ to help you deal with Date/Time in JS.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few methods that you can use to handle this [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) as seen below :

**Creating a Prototype Function**

You could create a very basic prototype function which would allow you to explicitly build a string using each of the components, which may be an excellent approach if you intend to reuse this function or similar ones often :

```
//Creating a Prototype 
Date.prototype.yyyymmddhhmmss = function() {
   //Grab each of your components
   var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
   var MM = (this.getMonth()+1).toString();
   var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
   var hh = this.getHours().toString();
   var mm = this.getMinutes().toString();
   var ss = this.getSeconds().toString();

   //Returns your formatted result
  return yyyy + '-' + (MM[1]?MM:"0"+MM[0]) + '-' + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]) + ' ' + (hh[1]?hh:"0"+hh[0]) + ':' + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + ':' + (ss[1]?ss:"0"+ss[0]);
};

//Usage
alert(new Date().yyyymmddhhmmss());
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/imezek/1/edit)

**Output as yyyy-mm-dd**

Very similar to the example above, you can directly build the string using the individual components of the Date object :

```
 //Create a Date object
 var date = new Date();

 //Concatenate the sections of your Date into a string ("yyyy-mm-dd")
 var formatted = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
```

**Output as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss**

This method is identical to the above with the exception that it also includes a few additional fields such as hours, minutes and seconds.

```
 var date = new Date();

 var formatted = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate() + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds();
```

Comment: is getDate, not getDay, also padding is missing

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to deal with the fact that month is `0` based (i.e. 0 = Jan, 1 = feb, etc.). For that you can simple increment the month value, when you get the 3 values:

```
var year = x.getFullYear();
var month = x.getMonth() + 1;
var day = x.getDate();
```

**NOTE**: You need to use `getDate()` for the day part (e.g. `31`). `getDay()` will return you the weekday (e.g. `3` = Wednesday)

Secondly, you need to deal with the single digit display. For that you can check if the value is less than `10` and if so, pad it with a "0". A little helper function can do this for you:

```
function pad(x){
    if(x < 10) return "0" + x;
    return x;
}
```

Which you can finally use like so:

```
var myDate = year + "-" + pad(month) + "-" + pad(day);
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/USTNb/)

Of course, as others have said, using a library would be much easier!

Comment: there are two problems: 1) you need to use getFullYear 2) is getDate and not getDay

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach that works for me.  It can be extended for all Date parameters.

```
var mm = currentDay.getMonth()+1;
mm = (mm<10?"0"+mm:mm);
var dd = currentDay.getDate();
dd = (dd<10?"0"+dd:dd);

$log.info(mm+"/"+dd);
```

Answer (score -2):

I know the OP asked about Javascript, but specifying Javascript was the wrong question, judging by the ugly (though correct) answers.
HTML doesn't have a way of printing the current date and time, and it should have.  Someone should invent one.
But PHP is the way to do what is wanted:

```
<?php print date("j M Y H:i"); ?>
```

PHP has 38 different format symbols covering every need, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: HTML is markup and it should not have to. It looks like the help was needed for the front side, not for the back. There a wide variety of solutions to have it done on the front. But yours would work on the back as well.